# Values in Wrong Columns After Pandas DataFrame.to_csv()

Tags: python, pandas

I am concatenating two data files using Pandas. The concat is working well but when I write the data back to csv the data loses some coherency:

```
# Define DataFrame 1
headerList1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
b1 = np.array([[0, 'B_foo', 2, 'D_one'],
              [3, 'B_bar', 5, 'D_two'],
              [6, 'B_cat', 8, 'D_one']])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(b1, columns=headerList1)

# Define DataFrame 2
headerList2 = ['C', 'E', 'F', 'G']
b2 = np.array([[12, 'E_foo', 2, 'G_one'],
              [15, 'E_bar', 5, 'G_two'],
              [19, 'E_cat', 8, 'G_one']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b2, columns=headerList2)

# Concat DataFrames
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

# Write to csv
scratchFile = os.path.join(dir, 'scratch.csv')
df3.to_csv(scratchFile, index_label=False, ignore_index=True)
```

I am looking for:

```
  A      B   C      D      E    F      G
  0  B_foo   2  D_one    NaN  NaN    NaN
  3  B_bar   5  D_two    NaN  NaN    NaN
  6  B_cat   8  D_one    NaN  NaN    NaN
NaN    NaN  12    NaN  E_foo    2  G_one
NaN    NaN  15    NaN  E_bar    5  G_two
NaN    NaN  19    NaN  E_cat    8  G_one
```

but get:

```
A     B     C       D       E       F       G
0     0     B_foo   2     D_one   Nan     Nan
1     3     B_bar   5     D_two   Nan     Nan
2     6     B_cat   8     D_one   Nan     Nan
3    Nan    Nan     12    Nan     E_foo    2     G_one
4    Nan    Nan     15    Nan     E_bar    5     G_two
5    Nan    Nan     19    Nan     E_cat    8     G_one
```

I can almost reach the desired result by removing index_label=False from the to_csv() command but this results in the addition of an undesired index column.

Is there a way to get the desired output without the index column?  Also, of personal interest, why does removing the index_label=False disrupt the column organization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df3.to_csv('df3.csv', index = False)
```

This worked for me. index = False means that the dataframe index is not included in the csv.